# How to divide up webscraping workload

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, virtual-machine

I have a massive webscraping project (Part 1 is scraping 300k+ separate data entries into a website). I may have to do more of these in the future and one data entry at a time just won't suffice. I have been using Selenium to enter the data into the JS site, and BeautifulSoup to parse the results. I have looked at Selenium Grid but I don't believe that will accomplish what I want because I'm not trying to have every instance perform the same function.

I would like to take those ~300k separate data entries and split them up to search, for example, 8+ at a time.

Is my only option at this point (in Python) to setup several VMs and execute my Python script in each? Current time to finish the scrape is about 30 hours.

Comment: Selenium is quite heavy on resources.  Why dont you try with requests or urllib2 ?

Comment: You may be right on that. The url stays the same and the content within the page is fetched with javascript. Selenium has been very effective with it and it just appears that it was one of the most recommended options out there. I'm very new to programming still so I probably made a poor decision.